# How to connect to database using C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

This is html form; I want to insert value from this form to my SQL Server table using C#. I try to add, but I do not know how to make correct connection and how to use data from this simple form to add it to database. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I have real database and server

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1> Find and search about any employee in Faten</h1>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <input id="ID" type="text" />
    <input id="name" type="text" />
    <input id="lname" type="text" />
    <input id="pass" type="text" />

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my C# code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO Ruser(ID, Name, Lname, pass) VALUES (@ID, @name, @lanme, @pass);";

    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection1);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", "33");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "abc");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lanme", "abc");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", "abc");

    connection1.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Check Error
    if (result < 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into database!");
}
```

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this one:

```
var connStr = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI";
using(SqlConnection openCon=new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
}
```

Or:

```
var connStr = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Userid=UserName;Password=Secret";
using(SqlConnection openCon=new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
}
```

But in the better way you sould save your connectionstring  in webconfig or if you use .netcore appsetting  file and read it from that.

Comment: Hi hasan I do all of this but still same problem no data added  to table Is there any problem in the rest of code as you see above

Comment: Mr Hassan has shown correct and very good code. You probably should surround the opening of the connection with a try catch and a using statement.

Comment: @ benjamin moskovits  yes ofcourse I just want to show about connectionstring but I edit my code and thanks for your attention.